# Maven PDF Plugin custom properties are not filtered in the generated PDF

Tags: maven, pdf-generation, maven-pdf-plugin

I am trying to generate a PDF and the main generation works fine, but I face the issue trying to use custom defined properties.
I do have the my properties defined in `pom.xml` as documented, but when I use them in the content files in the final result I don't see them substituted, but staying with the variable i.e `${myProperty}`.

e.g. I have the property defined in `pom.xml`

```xml
<properties>
   <myProperty>My other value</myProperty>
</properties>
```

If I use the same property in pdf.xml it is being properly substituted(i.e on the title tah), but if I
set it in an .apt.vm file as `${myProperty}` it doesn't.
The apt file is also with .vm extension as documented on the site.

On the other hand system properties as `${project.name}` work fine.

Do you have an idea what am I missing?

Comment: Did you solve that problem? Same problem here with the `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pdf-plugin:1.2:pdf`

Comment: I reported it as bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPDF-66